# Install snap downloaded from the web?

Tags: software-installation, snap, downloads

I need to use the application [Quirkos](https://www.quirkos.com/index.html), and for some reason they provide Linux versions as a snap package, which is not in any of the snap repos. Thus, the snap has to be downloaded from their homepage and installed manually.

What is the safest way to do this? As far as I can see, they do not even provide any way of verifying the download.

If at all, I would like to install the snap in a strict sandbox, is this simply done via
`snap install quirkos_1.5.2_amd64.snap --strict`?

I am fairly new to Ubuntu, how much of a security risk is the installation of an application in this way?

Comment: *how much of a security risk is the installation of an application in this way* -- opinion based. As always, it depends.

Comment: The Snap Store has no payment mechanism, so an independent download for commercial software is expected. If you trust the source website, then snapd will keep *security risk* to a minimum. Legitimate snaps, supervised by snapd, are designed to be very safe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how do I know if this snap is supervised by snapd?

Comment: If you use `sudo snap` to install it, then it's supervised by snapd.

Comment: Ok, so turns out the snap is not signed, which means it cannot be installed via `snap install` without the `--dangerous` flag. Are snaps installed via `-- dangerous` confined in the sandbox?